# How to click cell change height in tableView other controller?

Tags: swift, uikit, constraints

```
2023-09-20 09:57:39.883571+0700 Dokobit[5279:68007] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000370b890 UITableView:0x7f9d5082ba00.height == 106   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000370a4e0 UITableView:0x7f9d5082ba00.height == 159   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000370a4e0 UITableView:0x7f9d5082ba00.height == 159   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I want click cell in alert controller current make height tableview other controller change

```
func getValueCell(withValue value: String) {
    coutry = value
    btnAllCountries.setImage(UIImage(named: value), for: .normal)
    if (value == "Estonia") {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.heightTableView(height: 159)
        }
    } else if (value == "lithuania") {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.heightTableView(height: 106)
        }
    }
}

func heightTableView(height: Float ) {
    var tableViewHeightConstraint = tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(height))
    tableViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    print("OK")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning message you're encountering indicates a conflict between two constraints related to the height of the UITableView. Specifically, you are attempting to activate two different height constraints on the same UITableView simultaneously, which is causing a conflict. To resolve this issue, you should deactivate or remove the previous height constraint before adding a new one.

Here's an updated version of your heightTableView function that removes the existing height constraint before adding the new one:

```
func heightTableView(height: Float) {
    // First, deactivate any existing height constraint
    tableViewHeightConstraint?.isActive = false
    
    // Create a new height constraint based on the provided height
    let newConstraint = tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(height))
    newConstraint.isActive = true
    
    // Assign the new constraint to the tableViewHeightConstraint property
    tableViewHeightConstraint = newConstraint
    
    // Tell the view to update its layout
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: There's an easier way - simply change the `constant` property of `tableViewHeightConstraint` after setting it up initially.

Comment: tableViewHeightConstraint?.isActive = false ????

Comment: for deactivates the existing height constraint for the tableView if it exists. If there is no existing constraint, it does nothing.

Comment: how to get contrain height current I tried everything but it didn't work

Comment: tableViewHeightConstraint?